# upgrade server from 12.04 to 14.04?

Tags: server

Maybe I'm searching for the wrong words but I cant find a list of commands needed to do this.  Any help would be really appreciated.  Thank you.

Comment: `sudo do-release-upgrade` i think this is the command you looking for.

Comment: sudo do-release-upgrade returns "No new release found".  Im on 12.04.4